# .NetCore 2.0 secure store credentials in production "on premise" servers

Tags: security, deployment, asp.net-core

I've just had a wow when I've read that storing Api keys, connection strings in configs and push them to git(even in a private repository) is not good. I will need a secure website. I've google it and found some solutions for this but none of them is good enough.

1 use env vars. **Issue** exposed in plain text for user

2 keep then in a config file not pushed to git(put the folder/file in .gitignore. **Issue** exposed in plain text

3 The config should be encrypted and decrypt on start-up the config file. **Issue** the encryption/decryption key needs to be kept on server in plain text.
4. Like 3 but the encryption key is stored half in git half on hard. 
**Issue** this combine the git and plain text on server

Until now those are the versions I've reached over but they all seem to have a problem.
What is the **best option** you think of for keeping the api keys/ connections string /secret encryption string while using .netCore 2.0.

The deploy server is a centOs 7 "in house" server with a .netCore 2.0 and apache server as reverse proxy.

Comment: This is not a unique question and definitely not unique to .NET Core. If someone has console or filesystem access to your server, then all bets are off.

Comment: @CodeCaster I know is not unique question I just did not found a good anwser, for this until now

Comment: @CodeCaster so if the attacker has access to the server then it does not matter if the configs are in plain text or not. so the second option should be good enough. right?

Comment: You _could_ solve this issue with [user secrets](https://dotnetcore.gaprogman.com/2017/09/07/user-secrets-what-are-they-and-why-do-i-need-them/), as the config file that they're served in are hidden from view. But as CodeCaster has said, if a malicious actor has access to your server, then all bets are off

Comment: @JamieTaylor user-secrets does not run for production environment. they are only for development environment.

Comment: For sure. Never recommended that you should, just saying that there was another option. Plus User Secrets do run in a production environment, they're just not recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary concern is leaking secrets into your source control, especially if it's a public repository on something like Github. For that, you simply do not keep the secrets in your source. In development, you can utilize User Secrets and in production you can utilize something like environment variables or Azure KeyVault.

In terms of actually storing secrets in an encrypted way, Azure KeyVault is currently the only out of the box solution available. You can use KeyVault whether or not your application is actually hosted in Azure, though, and while it's not free, it's cheap to the point of being almost as good as free.

Other than that, your best option is environment variables. These can be set in a restricted way, such that only a particular account could access them, and then, you'd need actual access to the server to get that far. While it's not encrypted, if the values were to leak, it would take a situation that would make that actually the least of your concerns.

Finally, you can always write your own configuration provider and do whatever you need to do with that. For example, you could actually write a configuration provided that handled encrypted JSON, or one that utilizes Web.config, and then encrypt your Web.config.